# Is there a way to choose specific numbers from an array?

Tags: solidity

I have an array that I need to divide into 2 groups. The problem is I need them to be assigned evenly (group1 gets #1,3,5,7...group2 gets #2,4,6,8..etc).

I was able to do it by writing them all out with if. But causes Stack Too Deep.

Example:
uint group1;
uint group2;

````
if (addy == currentUsers[0] || currentUser.length = 1 || addy == currentUsers[2]) {
return(group1)
}
else {
return(group2)
}```

That's not my actual code, just an example. But I had to write it out
````

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus (%):

for example:

1%2=1

2%2=0

3%2=1

4%2=0

5%2=1

You will see anything divisible by 2's mod is 0 and everything not will be >0 (thus every second number)

So just loop through the array and use mod:

It will be something like:

```
uint i;
for(i=0; i<currentUsers.length; i++){

             //add array logic, this is just an explanation

if (i%2 > 0) {
return(group1)
}
else {
return(group2)
}

}
```

Obviously this will be wrong as I don't have more context of your code, but the method and way of thinking should be correct and help you get on the right track.

(Oh and use the SafeMath method of mod)

Hope this helps :)